# What is difference between Connectionstring and Connectioninfo in C# and crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

What is difference between Connectionstring and Connectioninfo in C# and crystal reports,Can i use Connectionsting instead of Connectioninfo.My requirement is i want use connectionstring only not connectioninfo is it possible?could you please somebody help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Connection Info provides properties for retrieving and setting options for connecting to database servers.

Connection String is your access path to your DataBase